# Boolean will not work with while loop

Tags: c++11, visual-c++

I'm having some trouble with my while looping breaking its cycle. If I answer the problem correctly the first time, it allows me to proceed through the program. However, if I use an integer it loops false, even if I answer it correctly in the loop it will not exit and save the string value. The thing is, is that I don't want a person entering an integer in this question, so I check the line for any integers.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include "ThreeWayRace.h"
#include <cctype>
#include <functional>


using namespace std;

void Options()
{

string carColor;
int carNumber;
int s;
cout << "Please type a color in for your car: ";
cin>>carColor;
bool contains_non_alpha
    = std::find_if(carColor.begin(), carColor.end(),
        std::not1(std::ptr_fun((int(*)(int))std::isalpha))) != carColor.end();
while (contains_non_alpha == true)
{

    cout << "Please enter letters only. ";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cin>>carColor;

}
```

Comment: `contains_non_alpha` is not set inside the loop. It's not going to change just by magic...

Comment: The boolean will never change thus the loop will not exit

Comment: In this case you might want to use [`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of), simply passing `std::isalpha` as the predicate. Instead of `std::find_if` I mean.

Comment: You might save yourself even more trouble by having a `std::set<std::string>` of known colour names, then using [`colour_names.count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/count)`(carColur)` to decide whether to loop asking for a valid colour name....

Answer (score 2):

As told by the comments you don't actually do the check in the loop, which means the value of `contains_non_alpha` will never change.

The simple solution is to do the check itself as part of the condition of the loop, no need for a temporary variable.

Using the [`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) function as in my comment you could then do e.g.

```
while (!std::all_of(std::begin(carColor), std::end(carColor), std::isalpha))
{
    ...
}
```

---

You could also use a `do while` loop like this

```
void Options()
{
    std::string carColor;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Please type a color in for your car (letters only): ";
        std::cin >> carColor;
    } while (!std::all_of(...));

    int carNumber;
    // ... rest of code...
}
```

Comment: ....I feel extremely silly for spending hours, upon hours trying to figure out how to check a string value for characters only..... Thanks a ton Joachim!

Comment: @NathanielPetterson Everything is easy once you know how it's done. :)